# c++ graph implementation getting stackoverflow error

Tags: c++, pointers, graph

I am implementing Graph in c++ (pls dont suggest to use STL) but the problem is related to general c++ initializations.
Its basically maintaining an array of linked list. The problem is insertion in the linked list, specially for the "next" pointer.
The array itself is of objects and not pointers
EdgeNode edges[MAX_VERTICES]
and I want to keep it this way for learning purposes. EdgeNode class contains a pointer to itself for the "next" item in the linked list.

Insertion causes a stackoverflow because I store the reference of temp object (that has a member pointer) that causes exception when the temp object goes out of scope. I even added a constructor assignment operator but that did not help either. How do I properly insert item in linkedlist stored as an array of objects?

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Graph graph;    
    graph.insertEdge(1, 11);
}

#include <iostream>

const int MAX_VERTICES = 1000;
class EdgeNode {
    int y{ -1 };
    int weight{ 1 };
    EdgeNode* next{ nullptr };  
public: 
    EdgeNode() : y(-1), weight(1), next(nullptr) {}
    EdgeNode(int _y, int _weight, EdgeNode* _next) : y{ _y }, weight{ _weight }, next(_next) {}
    int getY() const { return y; } ;
    int getWeight() const { return weight; };
    EdgeNode* getNext() const { return next; };
    bool const isEmpty() { return y == -1; }
    void const print() {
        std::cout << getY() << "(weight=" << getWeight() << "),";
    }
EdgeNode& operator=(const EdgeNode& other) {
    this->next = other.getNext();
    this->y = other.getY();
    this->weight = other.getWeight();
    return *this;
}
    ~EdgeNode() {
        EdgeNode* current = this;
        EdgeNode* next = nullptr;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            next = current->getNext();
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        delete current;
    }
    
};

class Graph {
    EdgeNode edges[MAX_VERTICES];//I want to use objects array, NOT a pointer array
    int degree[MAX_VERTICES]{ 0 };
    int verticesCount{ 0 };
    int edgesCount{ 0 };
public:
    Graph() {};
    void insertEdge(int x, int y) { insertEdge(x, y, 1, false); }
    void insertEdge(int x, int y, int weight) { insertEdge(x, y, weight, false); }
    void insertEdge(int x, int y, int weight, bool directed) {
        EdgeNode node = EdgeNode(y, weight, edges[x].isEmpty() ? nullptr : &edges[x]);
        edges[x] = node;
        degree[x]++;
        verticesCount++;
        edgesCount++;
        if (directed) {
            insertEdge(y, x, weight, false);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You should never `delete` anything that you didn't create with `new`.

Comment: `EdgeNode` is missing the user-defined copy constructor, and you didn't post a [mcve].  And yes, why are you issuing `delete` calls on pointers where `EdgeNode` has no idea where they came from?

Comment: i have the main() as we as the code. this exact code when run with main will cause a stackoverflow error

Comment: I see. so you mean even though  EdgeNode* next{ nullptr }; is a pointer but since it is always set by the graph class by passing address of an object, we dont need to delete it, because we never new it?

Comment: @bsobaid -- Basically your design is flawed.  `EdgeNode` has no idea where that pointer comes from.  What if it actually did come from a `new` call?  What if it didn't (as it is now) come from a call to `new`?  What decision will `EdgeNode` make as to what to do with that pointer in the destructor?  See the issue with your design?

Comment: I guess then the class passing the new'd EdgeNode will have to clear it?

Comment: Only the caller knows how to deal with the pointer.  The `EdgeNode` class shouldn't get involved.  Also, why is all the logic in `EdgeNode` to do the deletion?  Shouldn't a node just be a a node, and the `Graph` figure out how to handle the nodes, including how to delete a chain of them?

Comment: I get your point. and removing the destructor fixed the problem. I always struggle with null checks for objects and at the same time try not to create pointers, because they are discouraged in c++11 and beyond, that have an easy nullptr to check again.